# Process Builder update records limit

Tags: process-builder, governorlimits, performance, cpulimit

We use `Process Builder` to update records. I'm getting this error for the mass update:

> UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORI: (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) ITA_IFM_Case_Trigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Could someone tell me the limitation of update record via `Process Builder`?

Comment: Process builder is SLOW when compared to Apex AND it does not have a CPU limit per se. It will exceed the 10 second limit and not fail and the very next thing that happens will fail due to the timeout. The only thing you can do is optimize as best you can and consider using apex instead of PB when you have a lot of packages and code that happen as part of a dml

Answer (score 3):

Flows built via `Process Builder` do indeed consume more CPU Time than `Workflow Rules`, which in turn consume more than `Apex Triggers`. If you are running into timeouts, you should move the logic to one of the more efficient options.

You can take a listen through [The Dark Art Of CPU Benchmarking](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions#/session/a2q3A000000LBRYQA4) for some more information. See also: [Should we use process builder at all?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139983/should-we-use-process-builder-at-all) and [Are Process Builder workflow rules more likely to violate CPU Time limts than a standard/old workflow rules?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83936/are-process-builder-workflow-rules-more-likely-to-violate-cpu-time-limts-than-a)